# the name of country appear in url?

Tags: php, url, search, codeigniter-url

I'm using codeigniter I have created dropdown in view like

`<?php echo form_open('trip/result', array('method' => 'get')); ?>
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="main-form">
        <select name="look_for" class="span4">
          <option selected="selected" value="0"> choose country </option>
              <option value="US">USA</option>
          <option value="EN">England</option>
          <option value="FR">France</option>
</select>`
I want the full name of country appear in url ,I have a lot of country so I have table in database for values in like(EN-US-FR) so I want to send full name and symbol of each country to appear in  URL to make SEO good for web site.

Comment: I want for example when user choose England ...the word England appear in url like www.prototype/EN/Engaland

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for friendly URLs! There are lots of articles about them all over the web. Just google for `friendly url apache`, if you use Apache Web Server, for instance! I already did that for you! Examples: [Friendly url using php and htaccess](http://www.edinteractive.co.uk/article/?id=48) or [Use Apache's mod_rewrite to make URLs more user friendly](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-apaches-modrewrite-to-make-urls-more-user-friendly/5068743).

In your case, you should change the value of the `option` fields to the long name of the country, but don't forget to filter "special" characters, like spaces or quotes! Actually, you should create another column in the countries table at your database, containing the "slug" for each country. So, "United Kingdom" would become "united-kingdom", for instance. There are some functions to do that, [like this one](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/59486-php-create-seo-friendly-url-titles-slugs/)!

If you are using Apache, your `.htaccess` could look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^countries/([a-zA-Z]+)$ ./countries.php?country=$1 [L]
```

Then, at your `countries.php` file, you would search the database for a matching country!